# OpenVPN missing parameter on OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: network, vpn, macos

I have a problem setting up VPN connection between my MacBook Pro with OSX 10.11 and my VPS with OpenVPN. The server is working correctly because I am using in on my iPhone with iOS 9.0.2, android 4.2 box and iMac with OSX 10.10. On OSX 10.11 I am getting this error using Tunnelblick:

> 2015-10-12 21:13:27 *Tunnelblick: OS X 10.11.0; Tunnelblick 3.6beta10 (build 4400); prior version 3.5.4 (build 4270.4395)
>
> 2015-10-12 21:13:28 *Tunnelblick: Attempting connection with macbook-pro; Set nameserver = 1; monitoring connection
>
> 2015-10-12 21:13:28 *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart start macbook-pro.tblk 1337 1 0 3 0 16688 -ptADGNWradsgnw 2.3.7
>
> Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Shared/macbook-pro.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn:1: macbook-pro (2.3.7)
>                                           Use --help for more information.
>
> 2015-10-12 21:13:28 *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart starting OpenVPN

The config.ovpn that is causing the problem looks like this:

```
macbook-pro
dev tun
proto udp
remote vps-server-ip 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
tls-server

<ca> 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<key> 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

<cert> 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
```

Of course certificates are populated with proper certs and IP is also correct.

Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: In your config.ovpn is your first line: "macbook-pro"? It looks like this one is unneded (and unsupported) parameter, perhaps your copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `macbook-pro` "option" is not recognised by openvpn...

Remove this line or comment it out.